# is it possible to load a page within the div element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Model</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {  

    //select all the a tag with name equal to modal
    $('a[name=modal]').click(function(e) {
        //Cancel the link behavior
        e.preventDefault();

        //Get the A tag
        var id = $(this).attr('href');

        //Get the screen height and width
        var maskHeight = $(document).height();
        var maskWidth = $(window).width();

        //Set heigth and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
        $('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});

        //transition effect     
        $('#mask').fadeIn(1000);    
        $('#mask').fadeTo("slow",0.8);  

        //Get the window height and width
        var winH = $(window).height();
        var winW = $(window).width();

        //Set the popup window to center
        $(id).css('top',  winH/2-$(id).height()/2);
        $(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2);

        //transition effect
        $(id).fadeIn(2000); 

    });

    //if close button is clicked
    $('.window .close').click(function (e) {
        //Cancel the link behavior
        e.preventDefault();

        $('#mask').hide();
        $('.window').hide();
    });     

    //if mask is clicked
    $('#mask').click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $('.window').hide();
    });         

});

</script>
<style>
body {
font-family:verdana;
font-size:15px;
}

a {color:#333; text-decoration:none}
a:hover {color:#ccc; text-decoration:none}
div.window{
  border-width:3px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:gray;
  }

#mask {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  z-index:9000;

  display:none;
}

#boxes .window {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  width:440px;
  height:200px;
  display:none;

  z-index:9999;
  padding:20px;
}

#boxes #dialog {
  width:375px; 
  height:203px;
  padding:10px;
  background-color:#ffffff;
}


#dialog1 .d-header {
  background:url(images/login-header.png) no-repeat 0 0 transparent; 
  width:375px; 
  height:150px;
}

#dialog1 .d-header input {
  position:relative;
  top:60px;
  left:100px;
  border:3px solid #cccccc;
  height:22px;
  width:200px;
  font-size:15px;
  padding:5px;
  margin-top:4px;
}

#dialog1 .d-blank {
  float:left;
  background:url(images/login-blank.png) no-repeat 0 0 transparent; 
  width:267px; 
  height:53px;
}




</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
<li><a href="#dialog" name="modal">Simple Window</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="boxes">

<div id="dialog" class="window">
Simple Modal Window | 
<a href="#"class="close"/>Close it</a>

<a href="https://www.facebook.com/login.php"><img src="facebook-24x24.png" width="24" height="24" alt="Facebook" /></a>
</div>

  <div id="mask"></div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

After clicking a simple window link a div element is created. In that div element there is a Facebook button. On clicking that Facebook button it loads the Facebook login page in new window. Is it possible to load the Facebook page in that div element itself or any other ways to do like that?

Comment: Have you considered using an iframe?

Comment: @dcn no. i dont know about iframes???

Comment: if you don't know about iframes you lack knowledge about HTML. Since you are learning jQuery I think you have basically overstepped a lot of education. Like going to high school without having gone to the elementary. The example holds because high school builds on the elementary as javascript build onto HTML. :/

Comment: Then it is time to @learn about iframes (sorry, couldn't resist) :)

Comment: @dcn @Marino Simic @Felix Kling i have tried with iframe. it is not working.....

Comment: @learn" What do you mean with *it is not working*? `iframes` are made for loading other websites (which seems to be exactly what you want to do).

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is no (unless your using coldfusion with their  tag) you can also use Iframes but this will open you up to cross site scripting. You have started me wondering if it would be possible to tke the contents of the page you are calling via another page, accessed via an ajax call to be presented within the div.

but I doubt you could truest that all css, images and associated scripts of that content would still link. It is an interesting question, but the solution to this problem will no doubt be more complex than the simplicity you have already stated (opening the facebook login in another window).

Comment: He would have to use a proxy to get the other page using ajax. Even then it would be a flat download of the html source and wouldn't include any external files that are included.